# Where does the go docker sdk gets fetched from?

Tags: docker, go

I can execute:

`go get github.com/docker/docker/client`

(from [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/sdk/)) and see the source in my `$GOPATH/src/github.com/docker/docker/client`.

But there is no such repository https://github.com/docker/docker/client.

Where does go actually get the source from? Can someone point me to the url?

Comment: https://github.com/moby/moby/tree/master/client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q:** Where does the go docker sdk gets fetched from?

**A:** As mentioned. https://github.com/moby/moby

I had trouble working out the answer like you do as well. But this is how I derived it in the end.

Like what you you did.

First, running `go get github.com/docker/docker/client`. This command `git cloned` a `docker/docker` project into my `$GOPATH/github.com` directory.

Then I went to the project directory and did a `git remote get-url origin` to find out the original source it came from.

**Output is**: https://github.com/docker/docker

Putting this URL into the browser redirects me to the *github.com/moby/moby* project, I think they must have setup a `dns` to redirect people to that URL.

I haven't lookup or read about how the `go get` command works but it seems like there is a little bit of smartness in there to tell it that `github.com/docker/docker` is the actual project's URL which `git clone` would perform against. Then the `/client` bit is just a submodule or a directory of the project that it is cloning from.